# How do I tick a checkbox in a table and modal window?

Tags: python, html, selenium, web, drop-down-menu

On a website, I need to click a checkbox in a modal window that pops up.

I can't seem to get the proper xpath for it.
I've tried:

```
req_checkbox = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//td/div/input[@data-id='34970']")
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", req_checkbox)
```

Also tried:

```
req_checkbox = WebDriverWait(usedriver, 15).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH,'//div[@class="grid-check-box"]/input[@data-id="34970" and type="checkbox"]')))
```

The data-id is what would make that checkbox unique as there is more than one checkbox with the same class. Here is the code snippet:

```py
<td role="gridcell" id="AddFromFirmMasterListGrid_active_cell" class="">
    <div class="grid-check-box">
        <input class="LinkServiceContactToEnvelopeMap" data-id="34970" data-idtoken="5F3244E8BF5E488D14E28C05BE2DD2C524B5E9F0" data-envelopeidtoken="0A1257B11E29C56650A270E56FD12007CDF2F917" type="checkbox">
<span></span>
    </div>
</td>
```

How do I solve this problem?

Comment: Have you tried the normal click? I would check first if the checkbox is located ` print(len(driver.finds_element_by_xpath("//td/div/input[@data-id='34970']")))`. If len >0 then we can see why the click not working.

Comment: This helped me diagnose and see if the WebElement(s) can be interacted with or not, thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try with this css selector :

```
div.grid-check-box input.LinkServiceContactToEnvelopeMap[type='checkbox']
```

Xpath would be :

```
//div[@class='grid-check-box']/input[@class='LinkServiceContactToEnvelopeMap' and @type='checkbox']
```

First check that in DOM, if there are multiple enteries then you will have to make necessary changes.

Let me know, if you have any more concerns.